# Draw text on a Panel

Tags: c#, winforms, text, panel, onpaint

OK, I fix everything, now is exactly what I want.
I have a `textBox1`, `panel1`, and `drawTexta` (a button).

When I click the button and choose a point in the panel, I want to draw the string from the `textBox1`.

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (SolidBrush br = new SolidBrush(Color.Red))
    {
        StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
        sf.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft;
        e.Graphics.DrawString(textBox1.Text, this.Font, br, point1, sf);
    }
}

private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    point1 = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
} 

bool flag = false;
Point point1 = new Point();

private void drawTexta_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    flag = true;
    panel1.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use a textbox and only draw the text on the canvas afterwards?

Comment: The only thing I know is that there is going to be a memory leak by `SolidBrush`.

Comment: @AlvinWong .net handles garbage collection. It's still a good practice to use using, however.

Comment: @Yatrix No, GDI+ resources **need** to be disposed properly (like putting it in a `using` block) because they are not GC-ed. http://dotnetfacts.blogspot.com/2008/03/things-you-must-dispose.html

Comment: @GolezTrol can you give me any further information about adding a textbox  ? OnMouseDown creates a textbox or ? I added using as well

Comment: @AlvinWong then thank you for teaching me something new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text isn't being drawn to `panel1` because you need to refresh it.

Add this code to `button1_Click`, after you set `drawText` to `true`:

```
panel1.Refresh();
```

That will make the static text show up.

Comment: I just learnt that `Refresh` is a combination of `Invalidate` and `Update`. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/subhagpo/archive/2005/02/22/378098.aspx